# Estimate of a product of functions where $1/p + 1/q >1$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I have the following problem. I need to estimate the following quantity:

$$|\nabla|^{-1}A u \nabla u \label{1}\tag{$*$}$$

I know that $A\in L^6(B_R)$, $u \in L^{14/5}\cap L^2(B_R)$ and $\nabla u \in L^2(B_R)$ where $B_R$ is a ball of radius $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.<sup>(1)</sup> Clearly, $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{14} +\frac{1}{2} >1$, so this is not in any $L^p(B_R)$ with $p\geq 1$. However I don't have to obtain an estimate in $L^p$. I would also be satisfied with an estimate in $H^{s}(B_R)$ or $W^{s,p}(B_R)$ with $s<0$ i.e. a negative order Sobolev space.<sup>(2)</sup> So I thought about estimating, for $-1<s<-1/14$,
$$
\begin{split}
\|Au\nabla u\|_{H^s} &\leq \|Au\|_{H^{-1/14}}^{\theta} \|\nabla u\|_{H^{-1}}^{1-\theta} \\
    &\leq \|Au\|_{L^{21/11}}^{\theta} \|u\|_{L^2}^{1-\theta} \leq \|A\|_{L^6}^{\theta} \|u\|_{L^{14/5}}^{\theta}   \|u\|_{L^2}^{1-\theta} .
\end{split}$$
where in the second step I would use Sobolev's inequality with $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{14}\cdot\frac{1}{3} = \frac{11}{21}$ and in the third step Hölder with $\frac{1}{6}+ \frac{5}{14} = \frac{11}{21}$. But I was wondering whether the first step is even remotely allowed. I know we can't really take products of distributions but the functions I'm dealing with here really are functions in $L^p$ spaces? I know this is all pretty hand-wavey and this is why I'm asking to clarify this or for you to suggest another path one might take.

<sub><sup>(1)</sup>All these bounds follow from stuff like energy conservation etc. but I don't want to bother you with details.</sub>
<sub><sup>(2)</sup> I need this for the Aubin-Lions lemma to work. Equation \eqref{1} corresponds to a term in the formula for $\partial_t A$. In fact the space I need to continuously embed is $W^{1,7/6}(B_R)$.</sub>

Comment: The hypotheses you listed are not even sufficient to make $A u \nabla u$ a distribution (no way to bound $\int A u \nabla u \varphi$ for a test function $\varphi$).  Additional regularity on $A$ could help (the derivative can be moved to this term).

Comment: What do you mean by $\nabla_A u \in L^2(B_R)$ ?

Comment: @AymanMoussa Typo, fixed it.

Comment: @TerryTao Thanks for the advice. In fact, I have a $\dot{H}^1$ bound (extends to a $H^1$ bound on $B_R$, right?) for $A$, again from energy conservation (whence the $L^6$ bound).

Comment: Since $u$ and $\nabla u$ are known to be in $L^2$, Sobolev embedding gives $u \in L^6$, which seems to expand the available options significantly.